# If $a$, $b$, $c$ are sides of a triangle, and the system $x^2-ax+b^2+ac-y=0$, $ax+bc-y=0$ has one solution, classify the triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, triangles

> Suppose $a$, $b$, $c$ are sides of a triangle and 
>   $$\begin{align}
> x^2-ax+b^2+ac-y&=0 \\
> ax+bc-y&=0
> \end{align}$$
>   has one solution. Classify the triangle.

Then $x^2-2ax+b^2+ac-bc=0$ has one solution.
$$\Delta_x=4a^2-4b^2-4ac+4bc=0$$
$$a^2=b^2+(a-b)c$$
Since $b+c>a$,
$$a^2<b^2+c^2$$
I think this means the triangle is acute. However, we still need to prove that $a$ is the longest side. How would you prove that?

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions carefully before posting next time: the tag description of algebraic-geometry reads "This tag should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry."

Comment: Assume $a=b=c=1$. Then $x^2-2ax+b^2+ac-bc = x^2-2x+1 = (x-1)^2$.

Comment: $a^2 = b^2 + (a-b)c \iff (a+b - c)(a-b) = 0 \stackrel{\because a + b > c}{\iff} a-b = 0$

Comment: Maybe triangle identities could be used.